# Dynamically Loaded User Control's Page_Load event Doesn't Fire from Handler. Why?

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, ashx

I have a handler (.ashx) file that I'm using to deal with Requests. Depending on the type of output needed, I want to load a user control that will present the data in the correct format.

I thought that when I created the instance of MyUC its load event would fire, but i guess not. I've even tried specifying my own event handler but that doesn't work.

For what it's worth noting, I can create the instance of the MyUC and assign the funds to its Funds property. It's the load event that I need to actually do stuff with that list of funds!

This is the code that i have, which doesn't work.

```
    private string GenerateList(IEnumerable<Fund> funds)
    {
        string html = "";

        Page page = new Page();

        MyUC myControl = (MyUC)page.LoadControl("MyUC.ascx");

        myControl.Funds = funds;

        myControl.Load += new EventHandler(myControl_Load);

        return html;
    }
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? How can I go about fixing it?

Thanks

Dave

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a Form control `HtmlForm` to render postback controls and then execute the page using Server.Execute()

Sources:

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/10/22/Tip_2F00_Trick_3A00_-Cool-UI-Templating-Technique-to-use-with-ASP.NET-AJAX-for-non_2D00_UpdatePanel-scenarios.aspx

http://www.west-wind.com/Weblog/posts/298307.aspx

Comment: yep, this did it. the missing piece to the puzzle was I needed to call Server.Execute(...);